# How to get complete path and name of each file in Download directory in Android

Tags: android, file, directory

I am going to develop an app, where user can choose File from a Download directory. Now i need the path + name of the file, which the user has chosen.

```
DownloadManager dm = (DownlaodManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
```

By this way the user can choose the file. Now i need the absoloute path of the file, which is choosen. But the problem here is, if the user chosse a file, the file will be open(this shouldn't be happen)

Can anyone of you help me with that?

Comment: what did you try so far? show us your code

Comment: DownloadManager dm = (DownlaodManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
By this way the user can choose the file. Now i need the absoloute path of the file, which is choosen. But the problem here is, if the user chosse a file, the file will be open(this schouldn't be hapen)

Comment: please add it to question not to comment

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use,
`Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);` 
to access the folder, and `File.listFiles()` to access individual files from that directory.

See this rough example,

write a method to browse and list each file from `Downloads` directory,
and if a *directory* is found in `Downloads` folder, list its files too,

```
public void getFilesFromDir(File filesFromSD) {

    File listAllFiles[] = filesFromSD.listFiles();

    if (listAllFiles != null && listAllFiles.length > 0) {
        for (File currentFile : listAllFiles) {
            if (currentFile.isDirectory()) {
                getFilesFromDir(currentFile);
            } else {
                if (currentFile.getName().endsWith("")) {
                    // File absolute path
                    Log.e("File path", currentFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    // File Name
                    Log.e("File path", currentFile.getName());

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Get the path of your `Downloads` directory and pass it as parameter in your above method,

```
File downloadDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath());

getFilesFromDir(downloadDir);
```

Comment: Done!
But anyway i had a second question. How i get the name from the file which is choosen by the user

Comment: @ramazan86, I have updated the answer on how to get a name of a file.

Comment: I have seen that Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).listFiles() is returning null at Samsung Galaxy S5. According javadoc, this is because Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) is not a directory. But then... how can I get the Downloads folder on that device?

Comment: Hi @Domin I am facing the same issue on Samsung S21 which is running on One UI 6.0 with Android 14, and my code is working fine on all the other devices including the Redmi, realme, etc. so if you have the solution to this problem by now then please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget you'll need to set this permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

You can use WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE instead.